# How to add another root element in the response schema

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, wadl

I have a xsd, which is having 2 schema : request and response schema. There is a root element for the response schema but not in the request schema. I want to add one more root element for request schema, please help me on this.  Below is my xsd :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
  <doc xml:lang="en" title="https://openapi.ariba.com"/>
  <grammars>

  </grammars>
  <resources base="https://openapi.ariba.com">
    <resource path="api/procurement-reporting-details/v2/prod/views/Requisition_SAP_createdRange_v2" id="Requisition_SAP_createdRange_v2">
      <method name="GET" id="Requisition_SAP_createdRange_v2">
        <doc xml:lang="en" title="Requisition_SAP_createdRange_v2"/>
        <request>
          <param name="realm" default="aaa" type="xs:string" required="false" style="query" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
                    <param name="apiKey" default="aaa" type="xs:string" required="false" style="header" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
                    <param name="accept" default="aaa" type="xs:string" required="false" style="header" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
                    <param name="Authorization" type="xs:string" required="false" default="aaa" style="header" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
                    <param name="filters" type="xs:string" required="false" default="aaa" style="header" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </request>
        <response status="200">
          <representation mediaType="application/json; charset=utf-8" element="root" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </response>
      </method>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</application>
```

I have removed the grammar portion as there are a lot of columns.

Comment: The file shown is not an XSD schema.

Comment: yes, this is the wadl file in which I have added the xsd schema in the grammar section, but now I have to add one more root element for request scema

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.